# Android (Spinner): How can I assign or convert an integer value to spinner

Tags: java, android

I was making a questionnaire system. I created 8 questions with 8 spinners. I'm creating the spinner using a string-array defined as follows:
In the strings.xml

```
<string-array name="rating">
        <item name="none">1</item>
        <item name="not agree">2</item>
        <item name="average">3</item>
        <item name="agree">4</item>
        <item name="strongly agree">5</item>
    </string-array>
```

In my mind, the system should be able to select the rating with the spinner and calculate to show the response "good", "average", and "bad" based on the total rating set through the spinner.

How can I assign or convert an integer value to the spinner in the MainActivity? since I need the rating selected by the user through the spinner for calculation.
Do I need to use ArrayAdapter since I can already show the spinner drop-down list with the entries @array/rating?

Comment: Why you not try set value as string and convert to integer when you select one of choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need ArrayAdapter because example from your question does not keep values just names.

```
public class Rating {

public String name = "";
public int value= "";
... Constructor, getters, setters ...
```

Now in your Activity

```
spinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);

ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Rating[] {   
            new Rating ( 1, "none"), 
            new Rating ( 2, "not agree"), 
            ...
            });

// Step 3: Tell the spinner about our adapter
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

And when you need selected value you can take it like this

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{
    Rating selectedRating = (Rating)spinner.getSelectedItem();
    selectedRating.getValue();
...
}
```